What are kraus operators of a qubit interacting a thermal environment?
Suppose a qubit that interacting a thermal environment. The thermal environment can be a thermal field for example. What is the kraus operators for this case?

One way to model interaction with a thermal environment (of some temperature $T$) is through so-called thermal operations. Given some system's Hamiltonian $H_S$ they're all channels $\Phi$ of the form $$\rho\mapsto{\rm tr}_B\Big(e^{-iH_{SB}}\Big(\rho\otimes\frac{e^{-H_B/T}}{{\rm tr}(e^{-H_B/T})}\Big)e^{iH_{SB}}\Big)$$ for an arbitrary bath Hamiltonian $H_B$ (of some finite size) and, more importantly, any system-bath Hamiltonian $H_{SB}$ which is energy preserving, that is, $[H_{SB},H_S\otimes{\bf1}_B+{\bf1}_S\otimes H_B]=0$.
For qubits this—up to negligible approximation effects—is characterized by two properties:

The channel is Gibbs preserving: $\Phi(\frac{e^{-H_S/T}}{{\rm tr}(e^{-H_S/T})})=\frac{e^{-H_S/T}}{{\rm tr}(e^{-H_S/T})}$
The channel is time-translation symmetric$\,$: $\Phi(e^{-iH_St}\rho e^{iH_S t})=e^{-iH_St}\Phi(\rho) e^{iH_S t}$ for all $\rho$ and all times $t$. Equivalently, $\Phi([H_S,\rho])=[H_S,\Phi(\rho)]$ for all $\rho$

cf. this paper (arXiv) or this paper (arXiv), Theorem 10 therein. The nice thing is that this reduces the qubit case to just three real parameters; assuming $H_S={\rm diag}(0,\Delta E)=\Delta E\,|1\rangle\langle 1|$ the corresponding thermal operations—in Choi form—are characterized by
$$
\mathsf C(\Phi)=\begin{pmatrix}
1-\lambda e^{-\Delta E/T}&0&0&re^{i\phi}\\
0&\lambda e^{-\Delta E/T}&0&0\\
0&0&\lambda&0\\
re^{-i\phi}&0&0&1-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\lambda\in[0,1]$, $r\in[0, \sqrt{ (1-\lambda)(1-\lambda e^{-\Delta E/T}) } ]$, and $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$
Finally, through the standard formalism this leads to Kraus operators
\begin{align*}
K_1&=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{re^{i\phi}}{\sqrt{1-\lambda}} &0\\0&\sqrt{1-\lambda}\end{pmatrix}\\
K_2&=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\lambda}}\sqrt{(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda e^{-\Delta E/T})-r^2}&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\\
K_3&=\sqrt{\lambda e^{-\Delta E/T}}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\\
K_4&=\sqrt{\lambda}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align*}
This includes the limiting cases $\lambda=1$, where
\begin{align*}
K_1&=\sqrt{1-e^{-\Delta E/T}}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad K_2=\sqrt{e^{-\Delta E/T}}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad K_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{align*}
as well as $\lambda=0$, where
\begin{align*}
K_1&=\begin{pmatrix} re^{i\phi} &0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\qquad K_2=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{1-r^2}&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
\end{align*}
